# Jquery Clone() modify clone after or before insert

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, clone

**Environment**

- Jquery -> function clone();
- [Jquery Ui draggable](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#event-stop)
- with $(this) we are on the div BOX level we could also use the [ui or events object](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#event-stop)

**What i want**

Copy the box but delete the class "hure" from the copied child

**Structure of the box to be cloned**

```
<div name="box">
    <a .../>
    <span..../>
    <span..../>
    <div class="eye"> <img class="hure"..../></div>
...
</div>
```

**2Consider**

- I use a general function for the drag and clone, so only in 10% of the cases there will be a img tag in it and the class "hure" can be found, in the others there are other input fields.
- the cloned elements are in the dom structure AFTER the original (maybe important for searching).

**My approach:**

Resulting that both class get removed, whytf not only the clone?

```
helper : function(ev,el) { 
        if ($(this).find(".hure").length > 0){
        return($(el).find(".hure").removeClass("hure").clone());}
        else 
        {
        return($(this).clone());}
        },
```

Thanks for any help, i am lost since hours trying to do that thing. I can't find code to differ the original from the ***g clone.

**EDIT**

An alternative way would be to do that AFTER the clone, i already tried that without success.

**my successless approach**

```
if ($(this).find(".hure").length > 0){ $(this).find(".hure").eq(1).removeClass("hure");}
```

**Solution**

```
stop: function() {
        if ($(".hure").length>0){
        $(".hure:eq(1)").removeClass("hure");}
        }
```

Comment: I encountered a similar frustration with using the helper callback in jQuery and was unable to determine how to properly persist the clone. I think it may be required to adjust jQuery's source code to accommodate your specific requirements.

Comment: Have you tried removing the class **after** cloning the element?

Comment: @travis that sounds awfull if i understand right - so no str8 method to do this in a simple way, even 4you ;)?

Comment: @Jason P +1 it was my first attempt doing "After" but without success, thx for any help- C my edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/aGBKX/)***

I came up with this workaround. Basically, once the drag movement stops there is an event that you can tie into. When you clone the element in the stop event, you can place it as you wish. It is at this point you should manipulate the clone. In the demo, its class "hure" is removed, and it is placed in the body. Placement can be determined here to be elsewhere.

```
$('.box').draggable({
 helper: 'clone',
 stop: function(ev,ui){
  //clone helper
  var copy = $(this).clone();
  //use exposed api to set position
  copy.position(ui.position);
  copy.offset(ui.offset);
  //search for the class in copy and remove it
  $(".hure",copy).removeClass("hure");
  //place element (this may affect position/offset)
  document.body.appendChild(copy[0]);
 }
});
```

Comment: +1 thx for working code. very unique idea with position, cool. in my particular case i use the solution like edited in my Q. please share if you think my approach could be troublesome. thx 4 the helping answer.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try.. clone first, then remove the class on the clone:

```
function (ev, el) {
    var $cloned = $(this).clone();
    $cloned.find(".hure").removeClass("hure");
    return $cloned;
}
```

Comment: thx. it drove me crazy that this not worked, no chance to differ the clone from the original.